# Why does ipconfig show multiple DNS servers?

Tags: dns

```
$ ipconfig /all
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . . : a.b.c.d
                                      a.b.c.e
```

Why do I have two DNS servers listed? Is it something like try second in case first fails?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yep, exactly correct, redundancy.

Most big DNS providers always give two addresses in the event that one fails.

[Google](http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/) - Configure your network settings to use the IP addresses 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers or

[OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) - 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220

Comment: +1 - In Windows the terminology is "Primary DNS" and "Backup DNS"

Comment: I like the public verizon DNS too, 4.2.2.1 and 4.2.2.2

Comment: @JNK +1, also as a side note, on Windows, if you click the advanced button then the DNS tab, you can have a lot more than two! (I am sure you will be able to do this in other operating systems as well!)

Comment: @JNK: 4.2.2.[1-5], and isn't it owned by Level3?

Comment: @grawity - it may be now, when I used it before it was a verizon public.

Answer (score 3):

Google has a program that they have released that will run speed tests on all of the most popular DNS servers including your ISP's.

http://code.google.com/p/namebench/

This maybe be of some use to you if you wish to tweak your DNS settings.